# How to remove ConnectionString from FastReport template?

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, fastreport

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application and I have a [FastReport](https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport) report file (extension .frx) that has a `MsSqlDataConnection` tag in the xml containing an encrypted connection string to the database that was used as the data source when working on designing the report.

In the application, I'm trying to get the report to use another connection string, but since the report has a connection string to default to it defaults to it and then I need to replace it with the one I want to get it to work. This is awkward code and I'd rather not have a connection string associated with the template by default.

I'm following [this guide](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/show/pass-connecting-string/) on how to get it to use a connection string I want and it states:

> If the report template initially has no connection to the data source, you can add it. Here is an example to connect to a database MSSQL: [code example is shown]

This is exactly what I'd like to do, but how do I get my template to not contain a connection in the first place? If I use that code example shown, the moment I load the report the connection string I set gets overridden to the one in the template.

Relevant part of xml below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can remove in the code using:

`report.Dictionary.Connections.Remove(jsonDataSourceConnection)`;

or in the designer just delete the connection

And after that the connection string will disappear in the template

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to update your connection:

```
report1.Load("Get You frx file"); 

    report1.Dictionary.Connections[0].ConnectionString = strConnection;

report1.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**